# Problema de PHPMailer en servidor VPS Ubuntu - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, phpmailer, fetch

Estoy subiendo mi aplicacion **PHP MVC** a un servidor VPS en **Google Compute Engine** con la distribucion **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64**. En esta aplicacion tengo implementado un controlador para el envio de correo con PHPMailer, el problema es que cuando se hace la peticion fetch mediante JavaScript, el servidor me responde con un **505 Internal Server Error**. No se que pueda estar afectando ya que hago la misma prueba a nivel local y me funciona perfectamente, llevo bastantes investigando y mirando el codigo linea a linea a ver que puede estar afectando, pero al final no he podido localizar el problema.

Estoy utilizando **XAMPP 8.0.7** dentro de la maquina virtual con ubuntu.

A continuación les dejo mi codigo:

**NOTA:** No estoy utilizando "composer", por lo que descargue la libreria y la importe de forma manual.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const URL = "http://34.67.243.191/";

function sendMail() {
        fetch(URL + "email/sendEmailAdd", {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(pop_up_wrap_add),
    })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response); // La respuesta que llega es POST 500 (Internal Server Error)
        });
    }

sendMail();
```

**PHP CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'lib/PHPmailer/Exception.php';
require 'lib/PHPmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'lib/PHPmailer/SMTP.php';

class Email extends Controller
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->session = new Session();
    }

    public function sendEmailAdd()
    {
        if(isset($this->session->get('user')['id_cliente'])){
            $idCliente = $this->session->get('user')['id_cliente'];
        }else{
            $idCliente = $_POST['cliente'];
        }
        $fechaReserva = $_POST['fecha_reserva'];
        $horaReserva = $_POST['hora_reserva'];
        $idMesa = $_POST['mesa'];
        $data = $this->model->getDataAdd(['id' => $idCliente, 'fecha' => $fechaReserva, 'hora' => $horaReserva, 'mesa' => $idMesa]);
        $email = $data['EMAIL_CLIENTE'];

        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                        //Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       //Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = '';               //SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = '';              //SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;                                  //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('*********', 'Notificaciones Reserva Ya App');
            $mail->addAddress($email);                          //Add a recipient

            //Content
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->addEmbeddedImage('public/img/logo-reservaya.png', 'logo', 'logo-reservaya.png');
            $mail->addEmbeddedImage('public/img/email_banner.png', 'banner', 'email_banner.png');
            $mail->Subject = 'Reservación #00890' . $data['ID_RESERVACION'] . ' agendada para ' . $data['FECHA_RESERVACION'];
            $mail->Body   = ' <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="es">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                    <style>
                    *{
                        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        box-sizing: border-box;
                    }
                    body{
                        margin: auto;
                    }
                    .container {
                        display: grid;
                        gap: 0;
                        width: 500px;
                        border: 1px solid black;
                    }
                    .header {
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        height: 80px;
                        background: #7a6563ff;
                    }
                    .header img {
                        width: 200px;
                        margin-left: 1em;
                    }
                    .image img{
                        height: 300px;
                        width: 500px;
                    }
                    .main {
                        margin: 1em;
                        font-size: 20px
                    }
                    .main h1{
                        font-size: 38px;
                    }
                    .main ul li{
                        list-style: none;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    .info{
                        font-size: 15px;
                        font-style: italic;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    .footer {
                        color: #fff;
                        height: 50px;
                        background: #7a6563ff;
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                    }
                    .footer p {
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="header">
                            <img src="cid:logo" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="cid:banner" alt="" /> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="main">
                            <h1>Reservación Sephia PUB</h1> <br>
                            <p>Se ha registrado una reservación para <b>' . $data['NOMBRE_CLIENTE'] . '  ' . $data['APELLIDO_CLIENTE'] . '</b>  con el correo electronico ' . $data['EMAIL_CLIENTE'] . '</p> <br>
                            <p>Los datos de la reservación son los siguientes:</p>
                            <br />
                            <ul>
                                <li>ID: 00876' . $data['ID_RESERVACION'] . '</li>
                                <li>Fecha: ' . $data['FECHA_RESERVACION'] . '</li>
                                <li>Hora: ' . date("h:i A", strtotime($data['HORA_RESERVACION'])) . '</li>
                                <li>Mesa: ' . $data['ID_MESA'] . '</li>
                                <li>Asientos: ' . $data['ASIENTO'] . '</li>
                                <li>Estado: Activa</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <p>
                                Si crees que se trata de un error, por favor comunicate con el administrador para obtener mas
                                información.
                            </p> <br>
                            <p>*POR FAVOR NO RESPONDER ESTE MENSAJE - CORREO GENERADO AUTOMATICAMENTE*</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <p>© Todos los derechos reservados | 2020 - 2021 | Sephia PUB</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
            
                ';
            // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            $mail->send();
            echo 'Correo enviado';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP MODEL**

```
<?php

class EmailModel extends Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getDataAdd($data)
    {
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare("SELECT reservacion.ESTADO_RESERVACION, MAX(reservacion.ID_RESERVACION) AS 'ID_RESERVACION', cliente.NOMBRE_CLIENTE, cliente.APELLIDO_CLIENTE, cliente.EMAIL_CLIENTE,
            reservacion.FECHA_RESERVACION, reservacion.HORA_RESERVACION, mesa.ID_MESA, reservacion.ASIENTO, reservacion_reserva_mesa.ID_RESERVACION_RESERVA_MESA
            FROM reservacion_reserva_mesa
            INNER JOIN reservacion ON reservacion_reserva_mesa.ID_RESERVACION = reservacion.ID_RESERVACION
            INNER JOIN mesa ON reservacion_reserva_mesa.ID_MESA = mesa.ID_MESA
            INNER JOIN cliente ON reservacion.ID_CLIENTE = cliente.ID_CLIENTE WHERE cliente.ID_CLIENTE = :id AND mesa.ID_MESA = :mesa AND reservacion.FECHA_RESERVACION = :fecha AND reservacion.HORA_RESERVACION = :hora");
            $query->execute(['id' => $data['id'], 'fecha' => $data['fecha'], 'hora' => $data['hora'], 'mesa' => $data['mesa']]);
            $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Conexion Fallida " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya intente mirar el "error_log" y me sale algo como esto

`[Fri Jun 18 20:40:26.232738 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23762] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jun 18 20:40:28.461983 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 24297] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jun 18 20:40:28.462041 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 24297] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Comment: tienes configurado los parametros para enviar el correo???

Comment: phpmailer tiene un modo debug puedes activarlo para validar que error tambien tienes pero pareciera que estas tratando de conectarte por https www.example.com:443

Comment: Es que creo que tiene algo que ver con la configuración de Apache, pero no se como hacerla, porque yo tengo configurado como SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER que es el nivel (4) pero no me envía ningún mensaje, solo recibo una error de JavaScript que me dice que **POST http://34.67.243.191/email/sendEmailEdit 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: error 500 es un error en php en el servidor ... no tiene nada que ver con javascript...

Comment: yo te recomiendo crear un archivo donde hagas las pruebas del php mailer ... una vez que este funcionando lo migras a tu framework

Comment: Revisa si tienes habilitado el módulo de php `openssl`. También prueba agregando: `$mail->SMTPOptions = [ 'ssl' => ['allow_self_signed' => true] ];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Detecte el error, lo que ocurría es que había un problema con los *require*, que no podían encontrar los archivos SMTP.php, PHPMailer.php y Exception.php.

Y por lo tanto salía el siguiente error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
```

> (Lo cual se me hizo muy raro porque la ruta es valida ya que
> en windows si me funciona correctamente).

Para solucionarlo lo que tuve que hacer fue instalar composer con las dependecias de PHPmailer y luego cargue las dependencias con el autoload como se muestra a continuacion:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Y ya despues de esto me funciono correctamente.